# Giving users the ability to tab through form

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Anyone know if there is a trick to giving users the ability to tab through the fields in an adaptive card in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: It is not currently possible to tab through fields of an adaptive card.